# VTK: Clipping does not always work with cylinders/spheres/cones

Tags: vtk, clipping, bounding-box, clip

I have a strange mistake:

In my program I create some objects and clip them at the sides of my bounding-box.

This works fine with cubes (even rotated ones) but only some times with cylinders, spheres and cones.

At some planes the clipping works as I want it to, but there are planes, on which the clipping does not work.

First I create a vtkPlaneCollection with six planes for the six faces of a cube:

```
 // create the plane-collection
vtkPlaneCollection *planeCol = vtkPlaneCollection::New();

// create some planes and add them

// YZ-PLANE
// yz-plane at xMin
vtkPlane *xMin = vtkPlane::New();
xMin->SetOrigin(0,
                0,
                0);
xMin->SetNormal(1,
                0,
                0);
planeCol->AddItem(xMin);
std::cout << "yz-plane at xMin added" << std::endl;
// yz-plane at xMax
vtkPlane *xMax = vtkPlane::New();
xMax->SetOrigin(1,
                0,
                0);
xMax->SetNormal(-1,
                0,
                0);
planeCol->AddItem(xMax);
std::cout << "yz-plane at xMax added" << std::endl;


// XZ-PLANE
// xz-plane at yMin
vtkPlane *yMin = vtkPlane::New();
yMin->SetOrigin(0,
                0,
                0);
yMin->SetNormal(0,
                1,
                0);
planeCol->AddItem(yMin);
std::cout << "xz-plane at yMin added" << std::endl;
// xz-plane at yMax
vtkPlane *yMax = vtkPlane::New();
yMax->SetOrigin(0,
                1,
                0);
yMax->SetNormal(0,
                -1,
                0);
planeCol->AddItem(yMax);
std::cout << "xz-plane at yMax added" << std::endl;


// XY-PLANE
// xy-plane at zMin
vtkPlane *zMin = vtkPlane::New();
zMin->SetOrigin(0,
                0,
                0);
zMin->SetNormal(0,
                0,
                1);
planeCol->AddItem(zMin);
std::cout << "xy-plane at zMin added" << std::endl;
// xy-plane at zMax
vtkPlane *zMax = vtkPlane::New();
zMax->SetOrigin(0,
                0,
                1);
zMax->SetNormal(0,
                0,
                -1);
planeCol->AddItem(zMax);
std::cout << "xy-plane at zMax added" << std::endl;


return planeCol;
```

and hand it to a vtkClipConvexPolyData

```
    vtkClipConvexPolyData *clipper = vtkClipConvexPolyData::New();

    // set the clipping-planes as planes
    clipper->SetPlanes(_planeCol);

    // return the clipper
    return clipper;
```

When ever I create an object, I create a new clipper (do I need a clipper for every object, or should it work as fine with only one clipper?) and clip the object after it is rotated

```
vtkCylinderSource *cylinder = vtkCylinderSource::New();
cylinder->SetRadius(r);         // set radius
cylinder->SetHeight(h);         // set height
// set resolution
cylinder->SetResolution(res);


/* TRANSFORM THE OBJECT */
// create a new transformation
vtkTransform *transform = vtkTransform::New();
transform->PostMultiply();


// rotate around z-axis by phi (= angles[0])
transform->RotateZ(- angles[0]);
// rotate around x-axis by theta (= angles[1])
transform->RotateX(- angles[1]);
// rotate around z-axis by psi (= angles[2])
transform->RotateZ(- angles[2]);
// translate the object
transform->Translate(x, y, z);

// create transforamtion-filter
vtkTransformPolyDataFilter *transFilter = vtkTransformPolyDataFilter::New();
// link it to the cylinder
transFilter->SetInputConnection(cylinder->GetOutputPort());
// link to transformation
transFilter->SetTransform(transform);
// update filter
transFilter->Update();


/* CLIP THE OBJECT */
// clip it
// create clipper
vtkClipConvexPolyData *clipper = _clipCreator->getNewClipper();
clipper->SetInputConnection(transFilter->GetOutputPort());
clipper->Update();


/* WRAP THE OBJECT IN A MAPPER */
// cube -> mapper
vtkPolyDataMapper *mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper::New();
//    mapper->SetInputConnection(transFilter->GetOutputPort());
mapper->SetInput(clipper->GetOutput());


/* WRAP THE MAPPER IN AN ACTOR */
// mapper -> actor
vtkActor *actor = vtkActor::New();
actor->SetMapper(mapper);
```

every actor is added to the vtkRenderer. And other objects are created the same way.

As I told, this works fine with the cubes, but when I i.e. create a cylinder, the clipping works at my xMin-plane, but not at the xMax-plane.

I don't see, what I should change and I don't know, why it works with the cubes...

Comment: ok, I "fixed" it:
I move the planes a little like 0.0000000000001 away from the real bounding-box. Now it works.
This is not the best way to fix this, but it works for me. If anyone has a better way to fix this, please let me know!

Comment: I changed my clipper to `vtkClipClosedSurface`. This works fine, even without moving it.